# R if conditional nested in for loop

Tags: regex, r, for-loop

This is for R programming, thanks in advance!

I have a vector of data that has a given year followed by some dates in the dd/mm format. I'm trying to go through the entire vector with a for loop and using if conditionals with regex to paste the year value with the date value (which is missing the year but occurs beneath the appropriate year).

vectors:

```
doc.year <- c(2014, Alabama, 10/07, Georgia, 11/07, 2013, Virginia, 9/21, GT, 12/12, 2012, Miami, 08/21, Cal, 08/30) #original data
year.vector <- (2014, 2013, 2012) #years are pulled from the original data
doc.date <- doc.year #create a copy of the original data
gameday.vector <- (10/07, 11/07, 9/21, 12/12, 08/21, 08/30) #mm/dd dates are pulled from the original data
```

My code:

```
for(i in doc.year){ #iterate through the raw data
  if(doc.year[i] %in% year.vector){ #if it is a year value
    season.year <- doc.year[i] #then assign that year to a variable
  }
  else if(doc.year[i] %in% gameday.vector){ #if it's not a year value and it is a mm/dd value
    gameday <- doc.year[i] #then assign that date a variable
    doc.date[i] <- paste(gameday,"/",season.year) #and replace the copied vector with the date in mm/dd/yyyy format
  }
  else{
  }
}
```

Desired output:

```
doc.date <- (2014, Alabama, 10/07/2014, Georgia, 11/07/2014, 2013, Virginia, 9/21/2013, GT, 12/12/2013, 2012, Miami, 08/21/2012, Cal, 08/30/2012)
```

Comment: Dont understand your question and dont understand your output. Can you please replace the '...' with real examples and quote all characters For eg if Alabama is a new row or value , please quote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Simon's solution is a good R solution but if you insist on sticking with loops you were almost there with your code:

```
doc.year <- c(2014, "Alabama", "10/07", "Georgia", "11/07", 2013, "Virginia", "9/21")
year.vector <- c(2014, 2013)
doc.date <- doc.year
gameday.vector <- c("10/07", "11/07", "9/21")

for(i in 1:length(doc.year)) {
  if(doc.year[i] %in% year.vector){
    season.year <- doc.year[i]
  }
  else if(doc.year[i] %in% gameday.vector){
    gameday <- doc.year[i]
    doc.date[i] <- paste(gameday,"/",season.year, sep="")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use for loops in R. If you think in for loops, you're better off using C, Perl, C++, Java or something like that. That said, assuming data in the form like

```
doc.year <- c("2014", "Alabama", "10/07", "Georgia", "11/07",
              "2013", "Virginia", "9/21")
```

You can get the desired pieces in one shot without any other variables:

```
## figure out which entries are years
is.year <- grepl("^\\d{4}$", doc.year)

## create a vector with years for all non-year entries
years <- rep(doc.year[is.year], matrix(rle(is.year)$len,2)[2,] / 2)

## paste together the dates
dates <- paste(matrix(doc.year[!is.year],2)[2,], years, sep='/')
```

For any sane R processing you would just create a data frame with the result:

```
> data.frame(place=matrix(doc.year[!is.year],2)[1,], date=dates)
     place       date
1  Alabama 10/07/2014
2  Georgia 11/07/2014
3 Virginia  9/21/2013
```

If you really want to go back and patch the `doc.year` you can, e.g.:

```
doc.year[grep("/", doc.year)] <- dates

> doc.year
[1] "2014"       "Alabama"    "10/07/2014" "Georgia"    "11/07/2014"
[6] "2013"       "Virginia"   "9/21/2013"
```